# How to remove SPO user profile with out deleting AAD account

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, my-site

I have a bunch of accounts disabled in AD. These users left the organization. However we do not delete their accounts incase they come back.

This creates issues in 0365 people search. I would like to delete their UPSA User Profile so that they will not show up in any search.

I tried **Remove-PnPUserProfile** but I keep getting this error:
**"username@mydomain.com must be first be deleted from AAD before the user profile can be deleted"**

Is there a way to delete the profile without deleting the AAD account? I can do this from the UI but I need to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

If you are syncing with your on-premises AD with Azure AD, you can create an OU on the on-prem AD Domain Controller named “EXITS”.
Then move all the former employees to the “EXITS” OU.
Then, configure your on-Prem AD  ➡️ Azure AD sync to exclude that OU.
On-premises, just ensure that all the accounts in the “EXITS” OU are disabled.  Before doing so, I would also generate a new password for the account - don’t use a default password - so that if the account ever left the “EXITS” OU, the user would not have access.